# Join dataframes in dplyr by characters

Tags: r, join, dplyr, tidyverse

So I have two dataframes:

**DF1**

```
X          Y    ID
banana     14   1
orange     20   2
pineapple  1    3
guava      300  4
grapes     1    5
```

---

**DF2**

```
Store      State   ID
Walmart    NY      1
Sears      AL      1;2
Target     DC      3
Old Navy   PA      3
Popeye's   HA      5
Footlocker NJ      4;5
```

---

I join with the following and get:

```
df1 %>% 
  inner_join(df2, by = "ID")

X          Y    ID    Store      State
banana     14   1     Walmart    NY
pineapple  1    3     Target     DC
pineapple  1    3     Old Navy   PA
grapes     1    5     Popeye's   HA
```

But due to the semi-colons I'm not capturing those data points on the join, the end result should look like this:

```
X          Y    ID    Store       State
banana     14   1     Walmart     NY
banana     14   1     Sears       AL
orange     20   2     Sears       AL
pineapple  1    3     Target      DC
pineapple  1    3     Old Navy    PA
guava      300  4     Foot Locker NJ
grapes     1    5     Popeye's    HA
grapes     1    5     Popeye's    HA
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `separate_rows` from tidyr in combination with dplyr will get you there.

First table I called fruit, the other stores.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)


fruit %>% 
  inner_join(separate_rows(stores, ID) %>% mutate(ID = as.integer(ID)))

Joining, by = "ID"
          X   Y ID      Store State
1    banana  14  1    Walmart    NY
2    banana  14  1      Sears    AL
3    orange  20  2      Sears    AL
4 pineapple   1  3     Target    DC
5 pineapple   1  3   Old Navy    PA
6     guava 300  4 Footlocker    NJ
7    grapes   1  5   Popeye's    HA
8    grapes   1  5 Footlocker    NJ
```

Answer (score 1):

With `base R`, we can use `strsplit` with `merge`

```
lst1 <- strsplit(DF2$ID, ";")
merge(DF1, transform(DF2[rep(seq_len(nrow(DF2)),
        lengths(lst1)), 1:2], ID = unlist(lst1)))
#   ID         X   Y      Store State
#1  1    banana  14    Walmart    NY
#2  1    banana  14      Sears    AL
#3  2    orange  20      Sears    AL
#4  3 pineapple   1     Target    DC
#5  3 pineapple   1   Old Navy    PA
#6  4     guava 300 Footlocker    NJ
#7  5    grapes   1   Popeye's    HA
#8  5    grapes   1 Footlocker    NJ
```